# How to stream response body in pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid

I have a pyramid view and I need to sent the headers
and then stream the response body.

Here is an example:

```
def myiter():
    for i in xrange(100000):
        yield i

def myfunc():
    send_headers()
    for value in myiter():
         yield value
    end_request()
```

Is this possible with pyramid?

Comment: Check out [app_iter](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/response.html#pyramid.response.Response.app_iter) argument of `pyramid.response`.

Comment: Indeed this seems to work